# Save data to MySQL - json_encode

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with transferring data to the database.

So yes - I created a controller in CodeIgniter 3, which is to send data to the database.

Before sending, the data is checked using JWT.

My code PHP looks like this:

```
public function create()
    {
        $token = $this->input->post('token');
        $this->jwt->decode($token, config_item('encryption_key'));

        $payload = $this->input->post('payload');
        unset($payload['login']);
        unset($payload['email']);
        unset($payload['role']);

        $note = $this->input->post('note');
        $note = json_encode($note);

        $data = $payload;

        $data['note'] = $note;
        $this->notes_model->create($data);
    }
```

AngularJS:

```
 $scope.noteCreated = function( note ){
    $http({
      method: 'POST', url: 'api/admin/notes/create/', data: {'note' : note, token: checkToken.raw(), payload: checkToken.payload()}  }
      ).then(function (){
        $scope.success = true;


       $timeout( function(){
          $scope.success = false;
          $scope.note = {};

          console.log(note);


        }, 2000);

   },function (error){
      console.log('Blad we wczytywaniu danych');
   });
   }
```

The data it receives after sending it is in this form:

[image]

And they should look like this:

[image]

Problem: How to transfer data to get to your columns?

Comment: Why are you using json_encode, when what you want apparently _isn’t_ actually JSON? You probably want to fill `$data['note']`, `$data['id_domain_rel']` etc. with _individual_ values.

Comment: Exactly, the data $data['note'], $data['id_domain_rel'] is transmitted on the form - but they save as you see, and I would like them to go to the appropriate columns

Comment: You problem is  `$data['note'] = $note;` You encode data to json and  store into db. Simple pass array into `model->create()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save data into different columns, you have to make array like this:

```
$data['noted'] = $note['noted'];
$data['id_domain_rel'] = $note['id_domain_rel'];
```

now you can pass `$data` .

Please dont use `json_encode`.